# Prove the following $\neg((A\cap B)\cup (\neg A \cap C)) = (A\cap\neg B)\cup (\neg A\cap \neg C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

How can I prove the following statements are equivalent using laws of set theory?

$\neg((A\cap B)\cup (\neg A \cap C)) = (A\cap\neg B)\cup (\neg A\cap \neg C)$

Using De Morgans laws to simplify the first statement:

$(\neg A\cup\neg B)\cap (A \cup \neg C)$ but I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: You've already posted this exact question..

Comment: Why the duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

I switched notation for ease of typing on a mobile device. Let the sums denote unions, products denote intersections, and the primes denote set negations.

\begin{align*}
(a b + a^\prime c)^\prime &= (a b)^\prime (a^\prime c)^\prime && \text{DeMorgan's Law}\\
&= (a^\prime + b^\prime) (a + c^\prime) && \text{DeMorgan's Law}\\
&= a^\prime a + a b^\prime + a^\prime c^\prime + b^\prime c^\prime && \text{Distribution}\\
&= 0 + a b^\prime + a^\prime c^\prime + b^\prime c^\prime && \text{Complementation}\\
&= a b^\prime + a^\prime c^\prime && \text{Absorption}
\end{align*}